# jQuery - transparent and draggable text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, text, draggable, transparent

I had an idea to have a transparent text with with background image, so you can see the image through the text. After long search on internet I found this css solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7WP6f/

The code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="logo">
            <span>t</span>
            <span>e</span>
            <span>x</span>
            <span>t</span>
</div>


CSS:
#logo
{
    color: black;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 background: url('http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/6730501_700b_v1.jpg') repeat 0 0;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-size: 0;
 -webkit-background-size: auto;
 -o-background-size: 0;
}

#logo span
{
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    font-size: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now the thing is, I want to make these letters draggable so the background of the letter would "move", but simply adding jQuery UI draggable doesn't work (you can see it in example above, just uncomment the jQuery command).

Is there any way to achieve this effect? Only solution I was capable of, was making PNG's of the letter with transparent letter body on white canvas (in Photoshop), add background image to every single letter and with jquery.backgroundpos.js move the background while object is being dragged. Although this works, there is problem with white surroundings of the transparent letter (they can be seen when you move the letter on another one).

Thanks for any suggestions